# PECL installation conflict isssue

Tags: sql-server, linux, centos7, sqlsrv, php-8

I am trying to install Pear package using following command

```
sudo yum install php-dev php-pear
```

But it's giving me following error:

```
Transaction check error:
  file /usr/bin/php from install of php-cli-5.4.16-48.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ea-php-cli-1.0.0-9.13.1.cpanel.x86_64
```

I am installing this package for sqlsrv driver but I am not able to do.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you using WHM/cpanel right? Don't install extensions using CLI. You can install it using PECL installer in WHM dashboard.

here the screenshot of PECL module installer
[image]

But if the module is not available on the GUI installer, you can install the module using built-in PHP from the cPanel. the path of pecl executable is `/usr/bin/ea-phpVERSION-pecl`.

an example if you want to install sqlsrv on php 7.3:

```
/usr/bin/ea-php73-pecl install pdo_sqlsrv
```

reference: https://support.cpanel.net/hc/en-us/articles/360053132353-How-install-pdo-sqlsrv-to-connect-to-MSSQL-Servers

Comment: Thanks for your kind help. I am trying to install pdo_sqlsrv for php 7.3 using your command but it returns me the following message -bash: /usr/bin/ea-php73-pecl: No such file or directory. I checked php7.3 is available in /usr/bin/. Can you please tell me why I am not able to install in PHP 7.3.

Comment: Do you really add php7.3 in the WHM?
another alternatif path is `/opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/usr/bin/pecl`